# Manage hours and data in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm planning to study a small webapp in php. I am faced with a problem concerning an SQL query to be performed.
Basically I have to manage reservations based on the date and time. I have separated the two things in a form with a type = date and a type = time.

The date is "data".

The hour is "orario_inizio".

this is my form:

```
Data: <br><input type="date" name="data"  ><br>
Orario Inizio: <br><input type="time" name="orario_inizio" min="09:30:00" max="16:30:00"><br>
Orario Fine: <br><input type="time" name="orario_fine" min="10:00:00" max="18:30:00"><br>
```

In order for a reservation to be entered in the database it is necessary that "*orario_inizio*" we have a space of two hours, that is that in the following two hours there are no other bookings.

**input.php**

```
// Richiedente
$nominativo = $_POST['nominativo'];

$email = $_POST['email'];
$oggetto = $_POST['oggetto'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$orario_inizio = $_POST['orario_inizio'];
$orario_fine = $_POST['orario_fine'];

//inserting data order


$query1 = "INSERT INTO Prenotazione (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$orario_fine','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile')"; $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1 ); 
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1 ); 
?>
```

What I can not understand is how to develop a query that allows me to consider for the date chosen by the user that there are no bookings within two hours. Let me explain with an example:
The user1 wants to make a reservation per day 24 / sept at 10:30 am. I have to make sure that there are no reservations until 12:30. If there are no other bookings already made then I would like to enter this reservation if I send an alert.

I have done the second part, the insert into the database, but i don't have idea how to do about the first check.

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO Prenotazione (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$orario_fine','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile')";
```

I have read that a possibility should be the use of SUBDATE

Can you help me? thank you

UPDATE.

Table Prenotazione

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnbx1.png)

Comment: It seems, that you need to do processing on php, or create a stored procedure, which will check if the date/time is free. Note, if you are not filtering vars in your query, sql injection can be applied to your query

Comment: You can use the sql function `BETWEEN` to check the time *between* two times. Syntax: `time BETWEEN '10:30' AND '12:30'`. If *time* is *"between"* 10:30 and 12:30, then it will return the boolean value *1*. Build your logic around that.

Comment: @Martin 
Thanks for the answer, with this method can I go to check any time? In the sense that the user enters the time and based on that time, I check that the two-hour slot is free

Comment: Yep @user10395675. You can either handle the logic by subqueries, or break up the sql into multiple PHP variables if that's easier for you.

Comment: Example, your time between could be one PHP variable, and then you do a conditional check on that, e.g. when it's equal to 1 you throw your error, else proceed with insert.

Comment: Could you edit in your user logic, i.e. the *time* that needs to be checked against the two times in the question? That way it would be possible to formulate an exact answer.

Comment: @Martin 
I have updated my post to make it clearer

Comment: I was more thinking actual table schemas and relevant PHP variables to the question.

Comment: @Martin i update now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you provided no table schema, I'll have to use placeholder column names etc.

As explained through comments earlier, you can use the mysql function `BETWEEN` to see if something is *"between"* the given times (works for dates also). What it does, is it returns a boolean value. 1 if true, 0 if false.

assuming your table has a date row in order to see the bookings for specific dates, you could write the following example:

```
$sql="SELECT
        COUNT(column_id)
      FROM
        table_name
      WHERE 
        TIME($orario_inizio) BETWEEN '10:30' AND '12:30'
        AND date_column=CURDATE()";
$result_set=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$checkIfValid=mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $result_set)[0];

if($checkIfValid > 0) {
    //throw error
}
else {
    //perform insert query
}
```

You can tweak the logic to fit your liking a bit better. For instance, `CURDATE()` just takes the current date, but perhaps you have a specific booking date you can use?

This SQL basically counts an id of your choice (user id or whatnot) based on the condition that the time is *between* 10:30 AM and 12:30 AM, and that the date is today (could be a given booking date instead).

Now, if this sql finds any records, it will be put into the count. So it either has a value of 0 or higher. If the count is higher than 0, then that means we are *busy* or however the logic is applied, meaning that you cannot make a booking for that day / time period, and so we throw an error. However, if the count is not bigger than 0, then we proceed with our `INSERT`, because then everything must be okay.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You are right about the DB now i update my first post. 
I have tried your code ( i have change something because the hours that i wrote were only an example :) ). But if i do SELECT COUNT( id ) he gives me back all the books that i have done in this date.  For instance i have used this code: 
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Prenotazione WHERE '09:30:00' BETWEEN '09:30:00' AND '12:30:00' AND data='2018/09/25'.
And i have 1 book from 9:30 - 12:30 and a second one from 11:30 to 13:30. The SELECT COUNT gives me back 2.

Comment: If the count gives you back 2, then that means you have 2 users who has reservations within the given timeframes. If that's not the case, please add relevant tables with sample data and expected output from a potential query.

Comment: also remember that if your database has the date values as a `DATE` type, then you must make sure that your date values are using the format *yyyy-mm-dd*

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the problem is that 2 users can't do a book during the same period. If the first one books from 9:30-11:30 e the user2 can't book from the 10:30 to 12:30 because they are in the same period. Yes my date type is yyyy-mm-dd :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table(booking_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,booking_start INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (booking_start) VALUES (3),(7),(10);

SET @n = 9;

INSERT INTO my_table (booking_start)
SELECT @n
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.booking_start BETWEEN @n AND @n+2
 WHERE y.booking_start IS NULL
 LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------------+---------------+
| booking_id | booking_start |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             3 |
|          2 |             7 |
|          3 |            10 |
+------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- Nothing happens, because 10 is between 9 and 11.

SET @n = 8;

INSERT INTO my_table (booking_start)
SELECT @n
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.booking_start BETWEEN @n AND @n+2
 WHERE y.booking_start IS NULL
 LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------------+---------------+
| booking_id | booking_start |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             3 |
|          2 |             7 |
|          3 |            10 |
+------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- Nothing happens, because 10 is between 8 and 10.

SET @n = 7;

INSERT INTO my_table (booking_start)
SELECT @n
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.booking_start BETWEEN @n AND @n+2
 WHERE y.booking_start IS NULL
 LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------------+---------------+
| booking_id | booking_start |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             3 |
|          2 |             7 |
|          3 |            10 |
+------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- Nothing happens, because 7 is between 7 and 9.

SET @n = 4;

INSERT INTO my_table (booking_start)
SELECT @n
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.booking_start BETWEEN @n AND @n+2
 WHERE y.booking_start IS NULL
 LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------------+---------------+
| booking_id | booking_start |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             3 |
|          2 |             7 |
|          3 |            10 |
|          4 |             4 |
+------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- Success, because there is no value between 4 and 6.
```

Comment: mmh thanks for reply! In your opinion, in my case what i should use for the set? ( set @n )

Comment: Whatever datetime value you like. E.g. `booking_start BETWEEN '2018-09-24 12:00:00' AND '2018-09-24 12:00:00' + INTERVAL 2 HOUR`